# Android 9 App or MDM shutdown and restart, timeout screen or sleep

Tags: android, mdm

Good morning, everyone,
we're considering an application that will be installed outside the meeting rooms.
Our tablets are Galaxy Tab A 2019 version of Android 9.
We realized that we would like to have these features on the tablets:

- Turning off the screen and turning it back on at a certain time (or even turning off the entire tablet and starting up) - typically these are office hours: turning on at 08:00 in the morning and turning off at 8:00 in the evening.
- Avoid timeout after a few minutes...

We have MAAS360 and we can manage the Kiosk mode of this application.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the screen can be managed by any Android application.

To prevent the device from turning off screen, you need to add a flag FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON to your Activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

To turn off the screen, just clear this flag when you need to turn off (use AlarmManager to schedule the event), the screen will turn off in some minutes.

To turn screen back on, send a pending intent to your Activity using the AlarmManager, then use the following code to turn screen on in your Activity:

```
setTurnScreenOn(true);
```

To wake the device up from the sleeping mode, use WakeLock and add the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission.